# Deferring action until .each() has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, each, jquery-deferred

I have the following method:

```
function animatePortfolio(fadeElement) {
    fadeElement.children('article').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(900);
    });
}
```

I'd like to defer an action until `.each()` has entirely completed. Assume this is some version of deferred/promise I need to employ, but not understanding how in this scenario it would work.

Comment: what action should be deferred

Comment: @ArunPJohny Another animation that needs to happen after all the elements have faded in.

Comment: As I was saying below, do not use `done` with animation promises. Use `always` instead. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the promise object returned by animation

```js
function animatePortfolio(fadeElement) {
  fadeElement.children('article').each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).fadeIn(900);
  }).promise().done(function() {
    fadeElement.css('color', 'red')
  });
}


animatePortfolio($('div'))
```

```css
article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh, this is nice (waiting for the element and not its children).

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: That is incorrect. It is waiting for the collective promise of the children's animation queues, not on the parent element. (the return value from that `each` call *is* the previous `children()` collection)

Comment: Nailed it. I hadn't appreciated both `.promise()` and `.done()` needed to be used in tandem.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done with `done` function

```
function animatePortfolio(fadeElement) {
   fadeElement.children('article').each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(900);
  }).promise().done(function(){
     // do aditional animation here 
   });
 }
```

### OR

when function called do it there

```
    animatePortfolio(fadeElement).promise().done(function(){

     // do things here 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `done` with animation promises, as if any are in the target state to begin with it will not fire. Use `always()` instead

```
function animatePortfolio(fadeElement) {
   fadeElement.children('article').each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(900);
  }).promise().always(function(){
     // do aditional animation here 
   });
 }
```